# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException: Unnecessary stubbings detected.When looking to see if the method was called

Tags: java, mockito

I want to test whether the repository method on service. As I understand it, this needs to be done through spy, but it doesn’t work for me

My test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CrudApplicationApiApplicationTests {

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    private WorkerService workerService;

    @Mock
    private WorkerRepository workerRepository;

    @Test
    void getWorkerTest() throws Exception {
        Worker worker = new Worker("afsdfas", "ffeqwf1");
        Mockito.when(workerService.get(4)).thenReturn(worker);
        Mockito.verify(workerRepository).findById(4);
    }
}
```

My workerService:

```
@Service
public class WorkerService {

    private WorkerRepository workerRepository;

    @Autowired
    public WorkerService(WorkerRepository workerRepository) {
        this.workerRepository = workerRepository;
    }

    public void create(Worker worker) {
        workerRepository.save(worker);
    }

    public Worker get(int id) {
        return workerRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public List<Worker> getAll() {
        return workerRepository.findAll();
    }


    public void delete(int id) {
        workerRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    public void deleteByName(String name) {
        workerRepository.deleteWorkerByName(name);
    }

    public void update(int userId, Worker workerRequest) {
        Worker worker = workerRepository.findById(userId);
    }
}
```

But I just get an error at the Mockito.when() stage

Comment: How does the test look like and please post the full exception stack.

Comment: You don't make any call then to workerService.get()

Answer (score 0):

Since Mockito 2+ are mocked stubs strict. This means, if you mock something and it will not be called, you get the UnnecessaryStubbingException.

When you write unit tests you don't want to have setup code, which is irrelevant to the executed code.